# Kafka 0.9.0 end offset moved back on rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have 3 consumers working on a kafka queue (6 partitions in 1 topic). Config:

```
enable.auto.commit: true
auto.commit.interval.ms : 1000
heartbeat.interval.ms: 4000
```

I'm having a problem when there is a rebalance. Offset is moved back as seen in the example log below.

```
INFO  [2016-02-25 04:39:03,628] Consumer: Committed(Records = '3', Offset = '315377', Time = '2412ms')
INFO  [2016-02-25 07:31:13,302] AbstractCoordinator: Attempt to heart beat failed since the group is rebalancing, try to re-join group.
INFO  [2016-02-25 07:31:15,118] Consumer: Committed(Records = '3', Offset = '307104', Time = '0ms')
```

I don't see any errors that the consumers couldn't commit their offset. Any idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: what version are you using? can you show information about the topic and partition for the offsets?

Comment: Using kafka 0.9.0. Updated question with topic and partition info.

Comment: I don't understand the part that you are saying that the offset is moving back, maybe you can try to add more information to those INFO lines.
You should check the partitions before and after the rebalance to see if they are been distributed correctly.

Comment: I would guess it to have happened if one of the partitions was not being consumed and after the rebalance when the partition was assigned a consumer, the group offset went down. e.g. say Partition 1 was not being assigned any consumer when it got assigned the group offset would be less because of message lag. if you see your Partition1 lags than other partitions. So as suggested by @nautilus more info would help. I have seen this but not sure, why sometimes Kafka misses to assign a consumer to a partition and a rolling bounce of the consumers fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for comments, will enable more logging next time it occurs. Tried a rolling restart but that didn't help.